# Use Visual Studio Code as a Git diff tool

Tags: git, diff, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code has a nice built-in feature to diff two files.

Is it possible to use Visual Studio Code **diff** as the diff tool for Git?

Answer (score 19):

Like [Maciej says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63586546/6100005), *gitconfig* is the way to go.  With this I can set it up to be not just a difftool, but also the merge tool for Git.

```
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait $MERGED
```

I use [Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), to get the latest (but still stable) features ahead of time.

```
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[merge]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code-insiders --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code-insiders --wait $MERGED
```

---

There is now [official Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_vs-code-as-git-editor) for using Visual Studio Code as both a difftool and a mergetool.

In your *~/.gitconfig* file:

```
[diff]
    tool = default-difftool
[difftool "default-difftool"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
[merge]
  tool = code
[mergetool "code"]
  cmd = code --wait --merge $REMOTE $LOCAL $BASE $MERGED
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it’s possible.
You just must set up Visual Studio Code as your default difftool by adding this in your *~/.gitconfig* file:

```
[diff]
    tool = vscode
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

After this operation, just run a command, for example: `git difftool master`. After a few seconds, Visual Studio Code runs *difftool*.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official documentation:

*[Visual Studio Code as Git difftool and mergetool](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_vs-code-as-git-difftool-and-mergetool)*

**Content as of 2022-11-16 copied below, in case it moves:**

> You can use VS Code's diff and merge capabilities even when using Git from command-line. Add the following to your Git configurations to use VS Code as the diff and merge tool:
>
> [diff]
> tool = default-difftool
> [difftool "default-difftool"]
> cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
> [merge]
> tool = code
> [mergetool "code"]
> cmd = code --wait --merge $REMOTE $LOCAL $BASE $MERGED
>
> This uses the --diff option that can be passed to VS Code to compare
> two files side by side. The merge tool will be used the next time Git
> discovers a merge conflict.
>
> To summarize, here are some examples of where you can use VS Code as
> the editor:
>
> - `git rebase HEAD~3 -i` do interactive rebase using VS Code
> - `git commit` use VS Code for the commit message
> - `git add -p` followed by e for interactive add
> - `git difftool <commit>^ <commit>` use VS Code as the diff editor for changes

Comment: Related: *[What do we do with answers that are entirely copied and improperly attributed (only a "reference" link or similar is included)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/)*